# Scope Problem in a newcommand definition

Tags: macros, scoping

I am a LaTeX beginner, I am having trouble trying to implement the following code

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\site}[1][http]{{\bfseries #1://}}

\begin{document}
  \site{www.tug.com}
\end{document}
```

for some reason the bold effect only apply to the argument not the entire web site.
My intention was that everything passed to the `\site` command get printed bold face, the command also excepts arguments, ftp, https, and so on.

Would someone please explain to me why the scope of `\bfseries` is limited to `http` word only?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: The option for A4 paper is `a4paper`, not `a4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
\newcommand{\site}[2][http]{\textbf{#1://#2}}
```

`\bfseries` only applies until the end of the current group. The current group of `\bfseries` in `\newcommand{\site}[1][http]{{\bfseries #1://}}` is only the bit of the URL that reads `http://` (because you used two pairs of braces; had you forgotten the inner pair of braces, the boldface would apply to the current group of `\site`, which would almost certainly mean that the bold leaks out to places where it is not supposed to be). The rest of the URL is outside of that group and gets no boldface. In the example the old definition with one argument expands to

> ```
> {\bfseries http://}{www.tug.org}
> ```

Here it is easy to understand why the boldface applies to the `http://` bit only. Note that the braces around the `www.tug.org` do not get removed because `\site` only takes on argument, which means that the `{www.tug.org}` will just be read as is and not as argument of the command.

With the new definition `\site` actually takes *two* arguments instead of one argument as before. It is therefore easily possible to make sure that the rest of the URL is in scope of the `\bfseries`. As noted in the comments by egreg it is preferable to use `\textbf` here to recover the italic correction.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\site}[2][http]{\textbf{#1://#2}}

\begin{document}
  \site{www.tug.com}
\end{document}
```

[image: The MWE shows "http://www.tug.com" in bold]

The macro then expands to

> ```
> \textbf{http://www.tug.org}
> ```

and so the boldface applies to the entire URL.

You may want to look into the `url` or `hyperref` package for more URL handling that enables a nicer line breaking in case it is needed.

Comment: Better yet, `\textbf{#1://#2}` because this adds the italic correction.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for the suggestion! Edited it in.

Comment: Thanks a lot @moewe for taking the time to explain it this way, you really helped me.

Comment: @TamerAdel: The correct way to thank people is to accept their answer ;-)